# make the QMessageBox or QmainWindow in front of any overlapping sibling widgets?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

If the active window belongs to some other process,how to make the QMessageBox or QmainWindow of this example in front of any overlapping sibling widgets when timeout ?
I tried raise_() and activateWindow() ,but both don’t work on WinXP

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800,600)

        self.lcdNumber = QLCDNumber()
        self.lcdNumber.setNumDigits(8)

        layout =  QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)

        self.currentTime = QTime(0,0,0)
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.currentTime.toString('hh:mm:ss'))

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateLcdNumberContent)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def updateLcdNumberContent(self):

        self.currentTime = self.currentTime.addSecs(1)
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.currentTime.toString('hh:mm:ss'))


        if self.currentTime == QTime(0,0,4) :
            msgBox = QMessageBox(self)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle('iTimer')
            msgBox.setIcon (QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setText("Time Out !!")

            stopButton = msgBox.addButton("Stop", QMessageBox.ActionRole)
            ignoreButton = msgBox.addButton(QMessageBox.Ignore)

            stopButton.clicked.connect(self.timer.stop)


            msgBox.show()
#            self.raise_()
#            self.activateWindow()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify window flags by using `QWidget::setWindowFlags()` method of your QMessageBox or QMainWindow. You should use `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag for your purpose.
It will be something like `window->setWindowFlags(window->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)`.
If you will not succeed with just `setWindowFlags(window->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)`, you will need to use `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` with another flags. Experiment with it and you'll succeed.